# Invalid datatype for range function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table, range-partitions

I am trying to use range partition on a table for a column of type number. However, Oracle 12c throws an error saying it is an invalid data-type. I don't understand why/what is invalid in the command.

```
create table partition_tester (
    some_column number not null,
    another_column varchar2(10),
    partition by range(some_column) interval(10)
);
```

I am connecting to the database using SQL developer. It seems to have issue with the range function. On executing above script it throws:

```
Error report -
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the comma after  " another_column varchar2(10)," and specify at least one partition.

```
create table partition_tester (
    some_column number not null,
    another_column varchar2(10))
    partition by range(some_column) interval(10)
    (   
       partition p0 values less than (10) 
    )
```